# Tensorflow "ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor..."

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Currently trying to build a network of smaller 2D convNets in tensorflow. When i go to create the model after concatenating my blocks, im receiving a "Graph Disconnected" error.

Tried: Removing extra layers to determine the problem

Expected: the model to compile so that I could view a summary of the model

Real Result: received a "Graph Disconnected" error preventing me from creating the model

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Activation, Input, concatenate, BatchNormalization 
from keras.layers import Conv3D, UpSampling3D, Conv3DTranspose, MaxPooling3D,AveragePooling3D,GlobalAveragePooling3D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Conv2D
from keras.layers import add
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU, Reshape, Lambda
from keras.initializers import RandomNormal
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import os
```

```
def myConv2DBlock(x_in, nf, strides=1, kernel_size = 3):
    """
    specific convolution module including convolution followed by leakyrelu
    """
    x_out = Conv2D(nf, kernel_size=3, padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_normal', strides=strides)(x_in)
    x_out = BatchNormalization()(x_out)
    x_out = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x_out)
    x_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (2,2),strides=2)(x_out)
    return x_out

# it looks like we will have many Slice level sub-networks so we can easily use a for loop to create as many as needed using this function
def S2D_CNN_SLICE_SUB_NETWORK(vol_size):
    inputs = Input(shape=vol_size)
    layer = myConv2DBlock(inputs, nf = 8)  
    layer = myConv2DBlock(layer, nf = 32)
    layer = myConv2DBlock(layer, nf = 64)
    layer = myConv2DBlock(layer, nf = 128)
    layer = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(layer)
        
    return layer

# lets make a function to create the Slice level sub-networks and then concatenate them
def S2D_CNN_NETWORK(vol_size, num_slices):
    inputs = Input(shape=vol_size)
    slice_networks = []
    for i in range(num_slices):
        slice_networks.append(S2D_CNN_SLICE_SUB_NETWORK(vol_size))
    layer = concatenate(slice_networks)
    layer = Dense(128, activation='relu')(layer)
    layer = Dense(8, activation='relu')(layer)
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[layer])
    

    return model

testModel = S2D_CNN_NETWORK((128,128,1), 1)
keras.utils.plot_model(testModel, show_shapes=True)
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer without your code, the problem is a mistake in your code.

Comment: You are creating extra Input layers that are not used when calling Model(), so yes, these are disconnected, its not clear to me if you want one input layer or multiple, but you need to completely refactor this code to use either one input layer or multiple ones, and pass them to Model()

Comment: My end goal is multiple CNN blocks that will be concatenated together at the end, right now i just wanted to make sure everything was connected properly. Thank you! @Dr.Snoopy